# JAVA trying to read a file it sets nextChar equal to a box thing instead of the next char in the save file. where have I gone wrong?

Tags: java, arrays, save, load

this is a debugger error and runs an infinite loop where shown.
I am trying to load a file and have the gameboard be set to the chars in the text file (which are saved previously by user as shown) but in the debugger problem it sets next nextChar infinitely to □ after the first char has been read. I have had multiple attempts at trying to fix this myself but I cannot find a solution. Any help on how to fix this bug would be greatly appreciated. If any more details are needed give voice and see questions answered hastily.

This is the saving section of code.

```
 /**
 * A method to save the current state of the game
 */
public static void saveGame()
{
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    PrintWriter printWriter = null;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Please name the save game file.");
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(Genio.getString());
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(outputStream);
        int i, j =0;
        for(i=0; i<row; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<col; j++)
            {
                printWriter.println(gameBoard[i][j]);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry an error occured during saving.");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (printWriter != null)
        {
            printWriter.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the loading section of code;

```
/**
 * A method to load a game.
 */
public static void loadGame()
{
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    char nextChar;
    String line;
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of your save file:");
        fileReader = new FileReader(Genio.getString());
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        nextChar = (char)bufferedReader.read();
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<row; i++)
            {

                for (int j=0; j<col; j++)
                {
                    if (nextChar == '-' || nextChar == 'Y' || nextChar == 'R') //Infinite loop here where nextChar = □
                    {
                        gameBoard[i][j] = nextChar;
                        nextChar = (char)bufferedReader.read();
                        System.out.print(gameBoard[i][j]);
                        line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        nextChar = (char)bufferedReader.read();
                        j--;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println("1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7");
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry an error occured during the loading of the file.");
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bufferedReader != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bufferedReader.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, an error has occured when closing the file.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ps. Genio is a static class that holds code for user input.

Comment: Why are you reading a character and also a line? Should you not be reading the line and then processing that? Where does "row" and "col" come from?

Comment: apologies, I should have mentioned in the question. gameBoard is a char array set initially to char[][] gameBoard = new char[6][7], this is used to store chars in a 2D array so as to be able to play connect 4 (which is fully working but cannot be loaded). int row and int col are constant set to row =6 and col = 7. 

I tried to read the line as I was saving each char on a new line and reading the char to have it stored in gameBoard[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are reading a line AND reading characters.

You need to read each line and process each character in that line, for example...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class ReadConnect4 {

    private static final String TEST_BOARD = "-------\n"
            + "-------\n"
            + "-------\n"
            + "-------\n"
            + "-Y-----\n"
            + "-Y--R--\n";

    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLS = 7;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayInputStream pretendFile = new ByteArrayInputStream(TEST_BOARD.getBytes());
        char[][] board = readBoard(pretendFile);
        printBoard(board);
    }

    private static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
        for(int k = 0; k < board.length; k++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < board[k].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[k][j]);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static char[][] readBoard(InputStream stream) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
        String line;
        int row = 0;
        char[][] result = new char[ROWS][COLS];

        // Read each line, stop when end of file (line is null)...
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // For each column...
            for(int col = 0; col < 7; col++) {
                // Get character from line, store in array
                result[row][col] = line.charAt(col);
            }
            row++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-------
-------
-------
-------
-Y-----
-Y--R--
```

To answer your question "why does it read box things", it's probably reading the end-of-stream and returning the character equivalent of "-1"